# Parsing XML in python for numbers

Tags: python-2.7, xml-parsing

I am new to python as well as XMl. I am trying to parse an XML file, find the  values and the sum of those values. I have included the code as well as the data below.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
data='''
<place>
  <note>Test data</note>
  <hospitals>
    <doctor>
      <name>John</name>
      <count>97</count>
    </doctor>
    <doctor>
      <name>Sam</name>
      <count>97</count>
    </doctor>
    <doctor>
      <name>Luke</name>
      <count>90</count>
    </doctor>
    <doctor>
      <name>Mark</name>
      <count>90</count>
    </doctor>
  </hospitals>
</place> '''

tree=ET.fromstring (data)
for lines in tree.findall('place/hospitals/doctor'):
    print lines.get('count'), lines.text
```

When I execute the above code, I am not getting any output.
Then I changed the code to :

```
tree=ET.fromstring (data)
print 'count:',tree.find('count').text
```

and the output is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test2.py", line 26, in <module>
    print 'count:',tree.find('count').text
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'
```

Any help is appreciated guys.
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Element.findall() finds only elements with a tag which are direct children of the current element. The documentation for ElementTree is [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html). 
So are the code examples.

For now, try this:

`for line in tree.findall('./hospitals/doctor/count'):
    print line.text`

The above code just prints the counts. You will have to write the code to sum them up.